# I want to learn about virtualization

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, hypervisor

As a very beginner, I only know how to create VMs and install OS on these using Oracle VirtualBox. All the VMs created are dependent on the hardware resources (CPU, RAM etc.) of a single machine. If the machine goes down the VMs will go down. Need to know how VMs can be created using taking resources from different physical machines (manually or dynamically) to avoid failure of any VMs.

For example: There are 4 physical machines having 8 core and 16GB RAM each. Now, I want to create three VM having having 8 core and 16GB RAM taking from different physical machines. If one physical machine goes down, no VM will be down.

Comment: So basically you want to share bare metal resources across the VMs? Or are you trying to build VMs with failovers (physical box #1 goes down, #2 boots up the image)?

Either way I don't think it's possible to share resources like that (option #2 would be possible but not #1), but I'm no expert when it comes to virtualization.

Comment: One goes down and then another one boots up. I'm not thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up clustering solutions (e.g. VMware clusters, or Hyper-V failover clusters). In this model, if a physical host goes down, then the virtualization platform will power up the VMs on other hosts.

If you're looking for zero downtime, then VMware has something called Fault Tolerance in which a shadow copy of a VM is running on a different host and is continuously synchronized with the primary copy. If the primary host goes down, the shadow copy can take over with zero downtime (e.g. you don't have to boot from the shadow copy because it's already running). This feature, while cool, has a lot of real-world limitations in how it inter-operates with other features of VMware. For example, as of vSphere 6.0, you cannot do various kinds of migrations for such VMs, etc. I believe it also requires a more expensive license.

These solutions generally require some shared resources between the physical hosts (most notably storage). Otherwise they will not work (or at the very least, performance will greatly suffer).